# select items from one table that are not in the second table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a database in Access with 2 tables named Necessary_components and Actual_components

```
**Necessary_components data:**
ID     Name
1      comp1
2      comp2
3      comp2
4      comp2
5      comp3
6      comp3

**Actual_components data:**
ID     Name
143    comp1
164    comp2
166    comp3
```

Now I want to display the components that are missing from Actual_components (for the given example are missing 3 components: 2-> comp2 and 1-> comp3).

Below is the code that I used, but it doesn't work because it will not take in consideration if there are more components with the same name. There can be even 10 components with the same name.

```
SELECT Name FROM Necessary_components WHERE
Name NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM Actual_components) ORDER BY Name ASC;
```

Comment: According to your current data, all the Components are present in Actual Components. "SELECT Name FROM Necessary_components WHERE
Name NOT IN (SELECT Name FROM Actual_components) ORDER BY Name ASC;" will give you the components that are missing from Actual_components

Comment: By name, not by number. The output from query should be: comp2, comp2, comp3 -> these are the components that are missing.

Comment: You have a serious flaw in your table design, you should consider redesigning your tables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your Question. According to your current data, all the Components are present in Actual Components.
If say, You had a Component named - comp4 in necessary components then you would have got Comp4 using LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: As you can see in Necessary_components there are 3 needed comp2 and in Actual_components is only 1. The same for the comp3 (there a 2 needed comp3 and actual is only 1)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help you...

**But again, your table design is having the problem, fixing that is an easier solution for your future coding.**

-- not tested

```
   select N.Name FROM
(
    select N.Name, count(N.Name) [NecessCount] 
    from Necessary_components N group by N.Name 
) AS T1

Left OUTER JOIN 

(
    select A.Name, count(A.Name) as [ActualCount]
    from Actual_components A group by A.Name 
) AS T2 

on T1.Name = T2. Name
where [NecessCount] - isnull([ActualCount] ,0) > 0
```